# What are out Email options when hosting sites with Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, email, azure

I've been with Azure before, but there were too many issues that prevented me from getting what needed to be done in the timeframe that I had. Which was unfortunate because I really like Windows Azure.

I know I can send e-mails with SendGrid. Which I don't like. But I can do. But how do we have just a normal/typical email system setup with Azure where we can go to (for example): mail.mywebsite.com > Login > Check/Send/ email etc?

From memory, I don't even think Azure has an e-mail service.

Comment: You could use Google Apps.

Comment: This isnt really a programming question, its more a "Suggest" a tool issue. If its server related, you may be better off with serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure doesn't have an hosted email service. They are just a hosting platform. You could start up a virtual machine and run an email service from the virtual machine if you wanted.

If you like the Microsoft world, you're probably looking for something like [Office 365](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/business/what-is-office-365-for-business-FX102997580.aspx) which is Microsoft's hosted email solution today (and many many more hosted email solutions exist, just visit a search engine and search for something like "hosted email providers")

Comment: I am def a Microsoft kinda guy. Would you mind me asking a few more questions if I have any? I'm going to check out Office 365 now, but I already installed it (it came with Outlook, Word, Excel etc). I didn't know it had anything to do with hosted email. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user2645707 I'm not familiar with Office 365 beyond knowing it exists. As other commenters have pointed out... server related stuff is probably better suited for [sf] since it's not directly programming related.

Comment: Filling out the Trial form for Midsize business plan with Office365 it appears that Australia is not supported, since it looks like it's the only country _not_ on the list. Sigh. I really do need to stop getting so excited before seeing things first.